# Only using django forms for validation

Tags: django

After using django forms they appear great for validation but I'm still not liking the way the fields are displayed. 
Is it poss to only use the form fields for validation. 
I.e how do you pass just the form fields to the template ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can iterate the form and get each field seperately and do whatever you want to do:

```
<form action="/contact/" method="post">
{% for field in form %}
    <div class="fieldWrapper">
        {{ field.errors }}
        {{ field.label_tag }}: {{ field }}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
<p><input type="submit" value="Send message" /></p>
```

Hope this somehow helps ...